# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „wurde verschoben“ und „ist verschoben“?

Tags: passive, past-participle

**EDIT:**
Es geht definitiv nicht um den zeitlichen Unterschied zwischen *wurde verschoben* und *ist verschoben worden*.
Es geht um den Unterschwied zwischen *wurde verschoben* und *ist verschoben*.

---

In Bezug auf [verschobenes](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:verschieben) lese ich oft Sätze, die zwar dasselbe meinen, jedoch unterschiedlich aufgebaut sind.
Nehmen wir drei simple Beispiele:

- Eine (örtlich) verschobene (Web)Seite
- Ein (zeitlich) verschobener Termin
- Eine (örtlich) verschobene Datei

Nun zu den Sätzen. Man könnte folgendes sagen:

> - Diese Seite **wurde** verschoben.
> - Der Termin **wurde** verschoben.
> - Die Datei **wurde** nicht gefunden; sie **wurde** möglicherweise gelöscht oder verschoben.

Und so weiter.
Versus: (Zustandspassiv?)

> - Diese Seite **ist** eventuell verschoben.
> - Der Termin **ist** verschoben.
> - Die Datei wurde nicht gefunden; sie **ist** möglicherweise gelöscht oder verschoben.

Ich stelle fest, dass sich die Sätze in der zweiten Box, die *verschoben* als Adjektiv verwenden, falsch bzw. nachlässig anhören (vor allem der letzte).
Meines Erachtens nach kann man sie allesamt durch den jeweils passenden Satz in der ersten Box ersetzen (oder ein *„worden“* ans Ende setzen),
die Frage ist nur: Sollte man das auch?

Nach etwas Recherche stieß ich auf Artikel zum Zustandspassiv:

- [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zustandspassiv) zeigt ein Beispiel mit *geworden* am Ende, nennt es dabei aber Zustandspassiv,
- [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/Zustandspass.html) trifft hierzu keinen direkten Vergleich,
- [mein-deutschbuch.de](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/zustandspassiv.html) unterscheidet zwischen Zustandspassiv und Passiv Perfekt in einer Tabelle.

Wie ich lese, ist die zustandspassive Form also grammatisch valide. Die Beispiele des letzten Links bestätigen das.

Aber wie sieht es mit der Gebräuchlichkeit aus? Kann gewährleistet sein, dass die Bedeutung sich nicht verschiebt?

Folgendes Beispiel zeigt, wann die Bedeutung sich durch die Umwandlung definitiv ändert:

> - Ich bin gefragt worden.

vs.

> - Ich bin gefragt

Der zweite Satz meint etwas komplett anderes.

Sollte z.B. eine 404-Meldung, wie man sie oft im Web sieht, sich nicht eher auf folgenden Satz beschränken:

> Die von Ihnen angeforderte Seite wurde eventuell verschoben.

anstatt

> Die von Ihnen angeforderte Seite ist eventuell verschoben.

Comment: **Der** Passiv? Als ich das letzte mal geguckt habe war das ein Neutrum...

Comment: @tink: Ich glaube dein Kommentar hat sich verirrt.

Comment: Nur ganz kurz: Das sogenannte Vorgangspassiv in diesen Sätzen bedeutet: Irgendjemand hat das gemacht, wer, ist egal - das Agens wird nicht genannt. Die anderen Sätze mit _ist_ wirken auf mich spontan nicht wie Vorgangpassive, sondern wie um das 'worden' gekürzte, weil so umgangssprachlich übersichtlichere Passiv-Perfekt-Sätze. Letztlich ist es vielleicht in etlichen Fällen Auffassungssache, ob es sich bei solchen Sätzen um ein verkürztes Perfekt handeln oder ob dafür eine eigene grammatische Kategorie angesetzt werden soll.

Comment: Bei 'Ich bin gefragt' liegt der Fall anders. 'Gefragt sein' ist eine Verbindung, in der 'gefragt' nicht die ursprüngliche, sondern eine idiomatische Bedeutung im Sinne von 'populär' oder 'stark nachgefragt' hat, 'gefragt' ist hier schlicht Adjektiv (vgl. 'ein gefragter Typ'). Soweit ich sehe, ist das Verb 'fragen' nicht 'zustandspassivfähig'. Das Beispiel weiter unten von @Jan würde ich nicht so sagen, stattdessen '**ich** soll antworten' oder 'Der Polizist hat **mich** gefragt!' - Ähnlicher Fall: Der Kerl ist _erledigt_, er weiß es nur noch nicht.

Comment: Noch eins zu 'gefragt': Jemand kommt von einem Kundenbesuch zurück ins Büro, und der Kollege sagt: _Du scheinst ja ziemlich gefragt zu sein, in der letzten Stunde haben 10 Leute angerufen und nach dir gefragt._ **Dieses** 'gefragt' ist gemeint, es wurde **nach dir** gefragt, und nicht: _Du bist gefragt worden, und jetzt bist du also gefragt_ . siehe die Ausgangsbeispiele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dein Beispiel mit *fragen* zeigt sehr schön, wie sich Bedeutungen tatsächlich verschieben, wenn man vom Vorgangspassiv zum Zustandspassiv wechselt. Denn ein Zustandspassiv bezeichnet grundsätzlich einen Zustand, der in der Vergangenheit erreicht wurde und bis jetzt anhält – es ist sogar zu erwarten, dass er zumindest in der näheren Zukunft weiter Gültigkeit besitzt. Das klingt zwar zirkulär, aber so ist nun mal ein Zustand.

*Fragen* hat, in der Regel, eine aktive und sehr kurz andauernde Bedeutung. Ich frage *jetzt* etwas, das dauert fünf Sekunden (oder Minuten, wenn jemand wie ich wortreich daherschwafelt), anschließend ist die Frage gestellt und bereits Vergangenheit. »Ich bin gefragt« kann sich folglich nur auf den sehr kurzen Zeitraum zwischen »Man stellt mir die Frage« und »Ich fange an, die Frage zu beantworten« beziehen. Das alleine grenzt den Zeitraum, in welchem die Frage gestellt werden hat können, sehr ein. Im Gegensatz dazu kann ich bei »Ich wurde gefragt« ohne Probleme ein *gestern* oder *letztes Jahrtausend* einfügen. Es ist schnell ersichtlich, dass die beiden Sätze stark unterschiedliche Auswirkungen haben.

Etwas anders ist das bei dem Verb *verschieben.* Hier ist zwar die Handlung des Verschiebens möglicherweise eine sehr kurze (vor Allem, wenn sie sich darauf beschränkt, `mv datei ziel` in eine Linux-Konsole einzutippen). Allerdings hält der Zustand qua Definition nahezu unendlich an. Es ist für die Bedeutung von »Die Datei ist verschoben« völlig unerheblich, ob sie gestern, kurz vor dem Jahrtausendwechsel oder noch zu Luthers Zeiten verschoben wurde – Fakt ist, dass sie jetzt nicht da ist. Dadurch ist es unerheblich, ob der Computer, nachdem er die Datei nicht am erwarteten Ort gefunden hat, auf den derzeitigen Zustand (»… ist verschoben«) oder auf eine in der Vergangenheit liegende Handlung (»… wurde verschoben«) hinweist. Die Bedeutungen sind fast völlig gleich.

Es gibt natürlich weiterhin Unterschiede. Auf die Aussage »Die Datei ist verschoben« ist die Gegenfrage »Wann?«, nur bedingt sinnvoll, während sie auf »Die Datei wurde verschoben« ohne mit der Wimper zu zucken gestellt werden kann. Zur Veranschaulichung folgender ausführlicher Dialog:

> Die Datei ist möglicherweise verschoben, ich finde sie nicht.
>
> Von wem wurde sie denn verschoben? Und wann wurde sie verschoben?

Der erste Satz ist ohne Probleme im Zustandspassiv formulierbar, die Fragen müssen aber im Vorgangspassiv gestellt werden.

Ich finde übrigens nicht, dass »Die Datei ist möglicherweise verschoben oder gelöscht« falsch oder nachlässig klingt; für mich ist das völlig korrektes Deutsch.

Comment: Danke für die gut verständliche Erklärung. Das zeigt auch, dass das Beispiel mit _fragen_ kein besonders realistisches ist.

Comment: @Clijsters Wieso? A: »B, was haben Sie am Sonntag um zehn Uhr gemacht?« C: »Am Sonntag um zehn …« B: (fährt dazwischen) **»Ich bin gefragt!«**

Answer (score 1):

Deine Beispiele sind nichts anderes als der Unterschied zwischen Präteritum und Perfekt. Beim Perfekt wird die Handlung stärker betont. Es wird mehr in der aktiven Sprache verwendet. Das Präteritum wird öfter in Schriftsprachen insbesondere Zeitungen verwendet. Beide Ausrücke sind möglich und valide.

Zu den Passivformen gibt es folgendes zu beachten: es gibt den **Zustandspassiv** wie auch den **Vorgangspassiv**. Beide Formen können in allen Zeitformen gebildet werden (als Beispiel hier nur Präsens, Präteritum, Perfekt):

Zustandspassiv:

> Der Termin ist verschoben. Der Termin war verschoben. Der Termin ist
>   verschoben gewesen.

Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Termin wird verschoben. Der Termin wurde verschoben. Der Termin ist
>   verschoben worden.

Noch was kurz zu "gefragt": es gibt im Deutschen Wörter, die sowohl als Verbform oder als Adjektiv gebräuchlich sind. Das nennt man dann Adjektivierung. Auch Substantive lassen sich adjektivieren. Die Bedeutung ist dann ähnlich, keinesfalls komplett anders und lässt sich immer von dem Grundwort ableiten.

Comment: Wenn ich deine 3 Beispiele richtig deute, ist es nicht nur der Unterschied zwischen Präteritum und Perfekt, sondern auch zw. Zustands- und Vorgangspassiv. Eher darauf bezieht sich meine Frage. Da ich das wording hierzu nun kenne, werde ich das genauer spezifizieren.

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang ist auch zu beachten, dass sich hier deutsches Deutsch und österreichisches Deutsch stark unterscheiden (mit der Ergänzung dass auch die Umgangssprache im Süden Deutschlands eher den Gepflogenheiten der österreichischen Hochsprache folgen). Das Perfekt wird im deutschen Deutsch unter anderem als »vollendete Gegenwart« bezeichnet, während diese Zeitform in österreichischen Schulen unter dem Namen »Vergangenheit« gelehrt und verwendet wird. Im österreichischen Deutsch wird nicht zwischen abgeschlossenen und nicht abgeschlossenen Handlungen unterschieden.

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Wenn etwas weder jetzt gerade passiert, noch in der Zukunft passieren wird, wird dafür in Österreich die grammatische Zeitform »Vergangenheit« (also das Perfekt) verwendet. Auch wenn es längst abgeschlossen ist. Korrektes österreichisches Hochdeutsch: »Am 1. September 1975 ist ein Apfel von einem Baum gefallen, aber niemand hat es bemerkt.« In deutschem Deutsch müsste es heißen: »... fiel ein Apfel vom Baum ...«, denn die Handlung ist abgeschlossen und hat keine Auswirkung auf die Gegenwart.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Danke für deine Anmerkung, kurze Frage: Was ist dann der Präteritum in Österreich, wenn der Perfekt die Vergangenheit ist?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich würde den Perfekt nicht so stark vom Präteritum abgrenzen wollen (Hochdeutsch), aber du magst da mehr bewandert sein, hast du dazu genauere Quellen?

Comment: Ich habe folgendes gefunden: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfekt_im_Deutschen#Funktion_und_Gebrauch_des_Perfekts_im_Deutschen, das erklärt einiges.

Comment: Das Präteritum ist in Süddeutschland – mit Ausnahme der Formen *war* und *wollte* (in allen Personen) – eine reine Schriftform. Wenn ich es richtig in Erinnerung habe, ist es in Österreich genauso, nur dass die Ausnahme nicht gilt.

Comment: @Thomas: **das** Perfekt, **das** Präteritum? Oder ist es hier üblich, alle grammatikalischen Begriffe zu vermännlichen?

Comment: @Thomas: Du hast die gesuchten Informationen ja bereits gefunden. Das Präteritum wird in Österreich nur in der Schriftform in Erzählungen verwendet (zu denen man in diesem Zusammenhang auch Zeitungsberichte zählen darf). Wenn jemand diese Zeitform im gesprochenen Deutsch verwendet, sagt man er/sie »redet nach der Schrift«. Die Ausnahmen mit *war* und *wollte* gelten auch in Österreich: »Ich war im Keller, ich wollte schlafen«. Der deutsche Name für das Präteritum ist laut amtlichem österreichischen Lehrplan übrigens »Mitvergangenheit«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Interessante Anmerkung. Tatsächlich habe ich Sätze, die deinem Beispiel ähneln hier schon gehört (NRW). Aber wir wissen ja, dass gesprochenes nicht immer auch richtig ist.

Comment: @Clijsters: Heftiger Widerspruch zu »dass gesprochenes nicht immer auch richtig is«. Richtig wäre: »Für gesprochenes Deutsch gelten andere Regeln als für geschriebenes Deutsch«. Die Tatsache, dass Millionen Menschen beim Sprechen nicht den Regeln für geschriebenes Deutsch folgen, macht diese große Mehrheit nicht zu Leuten, die nicht richtig Deutsch sprechen. Die sprechen alle völlig korrektes Deutsch. Es ist ja deren Muttersprache. Nur sind die Regeln für gesprochenes Deutsch nicht dieselben wie für das künstlich geschaffene Schriftdeutsch, das so gut wie niemandens Muttersprache ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es ist Fakt, dass ein sehr beträchtlicher Teil der Deutschen Regeln (auch wenn sie nicht denen des geschriebenen entsprechen missachten. Meine Lieblinge sind _öfters_, _jmd. tut etwas machen_ etc. Aber das ist ziemlich OT...

Comment: @Clijsters: Das Wort »*öfters*« ist in Österreich und der Schweiz sogar Bestandteil der standardisierten Hochsprache, die in Schulen gelehrt wird, und in der amtliche Urkunden verfasst werden. Steht auch so im Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oefters Daran ist absolut nichts falsch. Und im Süden Deutschlands entspricht die Umgangssprache, also die Sprache, die die Mehrheitsbevölkerung spricht, in vielen Aspekten dem österreichischen Deutsch. Daher ist es auch z.B. in Bayern **korrekt** wenn man »öfters« sagt. (Ich meine damit ausdrücklich gesprochenes Deutsch, nicht Schriftdeutsch!)

Answer (score 0):

Die Sätze bedeuten nur in etwa dasselbe. Sie unterscheiden sich (semantisch) im *Fokus* der Aussage bzw. (syntaktisch) im *Aspekt* des Geschehens.

Die Vergangeheitsform lenkt die Aufmerksamkeit auf den Vorgang der Verschiebung. Wichtig ist dem Sprecher, daß jemand die Entscheidung getroffen hat, wer dabei war, etc.

Das Zustandspassiv lenkt die Aufmerksamkeit auf das Ergebnis der Verschiebung. Wichtig ist dem Sprecher, daß der Termin jetzt keine Gültigkeit mehr hat.

> Was ist gestern im daily call passiert? - Die Deadline wurde verschoben (und das erforderte einige Überzeugungsarbeit).
>
> Kann ich mich darauf verlassen, daß meine Ergebnisse am Mittwoch noch in das nächste Release aufgenommen werden? - Ja, die Deadline ist verschoben (und ist jetzt der Donnerstag).

Comment: »Die Vergangenheitsform lenkt die Aufmerksamkeit …« – du meinst »Vorgangspassivform oder? Vergangenheit alleine macht mE im Kontext wenig Sinn.

Answer (score -1):

wie schon mehrmals richtig erwähnt, ist hier der Unterschied lediglich die Zeitform. Perfekt und Plusquamperfekt oder *vollendete Gegenwart und Vergangenheit*.

Meistens benutzt man das Perfekt, wenn die Handlung vor kurzer Zeit endete oder die Resultate aus der Aktion bis jetzt anhalten: "Da er gestorben ist, muss ich jetzt mich darum kümmern."
Und das Plusquamperfekt dementsprechend, wenn die Handlung und die daraus folgernden Resultate in der Vergangenheit endeten: "Da er gestorben war, habe ich mich darum kümmern müssen."

Grüße

Comment: Wie in der Frage durch einen Edit schon vor dieser Antwort klargestellt wurde, geht diese Antwort an der Frage vorbei. Es geht um den Unterschied »wurde verschoben« und »ist verschoben«